# Accessing UniData through .net

Tags: sql, .net, u2, unidata, u2netdk

I'm having trouble with accessing UniData data from the u2.net toolkit.  I'm able to connect ok - have tested connections with the "Test Connection Tool" and in code, both connections work fine.  My problem is when I try and fill a dataset - using the sample code: I get this error:

```
[U2][UCINET][UNIDATA]:You have no privilege on file THENAME
```

Here is the code:

```
           U2Connection con = new U2Connection();
        try
        {
            U2ConnectionStringBuilder conn_str = new U2ConnectionStringBuilder();
            conn_str.UserID = "id";
            conn_str.Password = "pwd";
            conn_str.Server = "srv2";
            conn_str.Database = "DB.XXX";
            conn_str.ServerType = "UNIDATA";
            conn_str.RpcServiceType = "udserver";


            con.ConnectionString = conn_str.ToString();
            con.Open();
            DataTable schema = con.GetSchema();
            U2DataAdapter da = new U2DataAdapter("SELECT * FROM THENAME ", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string lStr = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
```

1 more note, I have an ODBC connection setup.  Through ODBC I can use the same credentials inside a SQL Server Linked Server to access the same query successfully.
Any Ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

By default, UniData grants ***no*** privileges to access files via SQL.

You will need to run `CONVERT.SQL` from the database to grant privileges to the file.

You can find out more about the command by either running `HELP CONVERT.SQL` on the command line, or [reading the manuals](http://www.rocketsoftware.com/u2/products/unidata/resources/manuals/unidata-7.3-documentation).

Comment: so even though I can access the data via ODBC from SQL Server - it doesn't mean that CONVERT.SQL has been run?

Comment: Is this issue resolved? Could you please try specifying column names instead of *. For Example : SELECT COL1 FROM THENAME;

Answer (score 0):

Could you please run TCL command ?

## select * from privilege;

Do you see THENAME there? For example, see enclosed screen shot for VOC file.

[image]

[image]